# Is there a way to have querySelectorAll search only the children of an element, and not all descendants?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

For example, if I have a snippet of a document:

```
<div> <!-- I have a reference to this: "outerDiv". -->
  <p> <!-- This is the <p> I want to select. -->
    <div>
      <p> <!-- I don't want to select this <p>. --> </p>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

(This is a hypothetical document. HTML parsers would not actually construct a DOM that looks like this.)

and a reference to the outermost `<div>` element, **I'd like to somehow use `outerDiv.querySelectorAll('p')` to select only the `<p>` elements that are direct children of the outer `<div>`.**

I can't use `outerDiv.childNodes` and search for the `<p>` elements because I actually have a selector that is much longer than `"p"` (e.g., it might look like `"p > a > b"`). I also don't have control over the HTML and can't use jQuery or other JavaScript libraries.

It's also not sufficient to prepend `"div > "` to the selector and apply it from `outerDiv.parentNode` since the inner `<p>` also matches `"div > p"`.

Is there a clean way to do this without having to parse the CSS selector myself, too much?

Comment: The only solution I know of requires looking directly at a subset of the `childNodes`. However, you say "I actually have a selector that is much longer than `p`." Can you post a more realistic selector that better reflects your situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `body > div > p` or whatever lies outside of the outermost div?

Comment: No, my elements may be arbitrarily deep and this gets hairy when there are multiple siblings with the same tag name higher up (starts requiring `:nth-child` in the selector).

Comment: can you set rules for `div > p` and then re-set the nested `div > p > div > p` to what it was before..?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but your comment gave me an idea. I can temporarily attach a class to the outer `<div>` (`outerDiv.className = "unique-name-123"`) and then apply `".unique-name-123 > p"`.

Comment: @ide: That would still select both `p` tags, wouldn't it? See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that you have a reference to the outer div you can use the below expression:

```
outerDiv.querySelectorAll(":scope > p");
```

This expression will select all p elements that are **direct** children of outerDiv element because as referred on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope)

> When used from a DOM API such as querySelector(), querySelectorAll(),
> matches(), or Element.closest(), :scope matches the element you called
> the method on.

---

(*in the following code snippet I dont use the example with paragraph because is wrong to put a `div` or `p` element inside a `p` element. Check these links about this: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p) & [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)*)

```js
//reference to outer div
let outerDiv = document.getElementById("outerDiv");

let selected = outerDiv.querySelectorAll(":scope > div");

console.log(selected);//it returns only the direct child div
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv"> <!-- I have a reference to this: "outerDiv". -->
  <div class="I want this"> <!-- This is the <div> I want to select. -->
     <div class="I dont want this"> <!-- I don't want to select this <div>. --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you go with Nick Pantelidis's answer, but just for posterity, here is another possible solution.

This uses [Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to test if the selector matches each specific child element (remember, unlike [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) only contains [`Node.ELEMENT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) nodes):

```js
function querySelectChildren(element, selector) {
  return Array.prototype.find.call(element.children, (child) => child.matches(selector));
}

let p = querySelectChildren(divRef, 'p');
console.log(p);
```