# Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>

Tags: html

From http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/aadivtag.htm

> In HTML 4, the DIV element cannot be inside another block-level element, like a P element.
> However, in HTML5 the DIV element can be found inside and can contain other flow content elements, like P and DIV.

I have something like this inside a form

```
<p> <label...> <input...> </p>
```

but when Rails auto-generates an error_explanation div wrapping the input, the one paragraph turns into two, and I see this in Firebug:

```
<p> <label...> </p> <div...> <input...> </div> <p> </p>
```

Also, if I just add a simple

```
<p> <div> test </div> </p>
```

the same issue occurs ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod0j53q/)) and it gets rendered in the DOM as

```
<p> </p> <div> test </div> <p> </p>
```

Why?

---

I later e-mailed the author of the article and she made the appropriate changes.

Comment: The link is broken: *"404 Not Found. Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."*

Answer (score 139, accepted):

From the [fine specification](https://w3.org/tr/html/grouping-content.html#the-p-element):

> **p – paragraph**
>
> [...]
>
> **Permitted contents**
>
> Phrasing content

And what is this *Phrasing content*?

[Phrasing content](https://w3.org/tr/html/dom.html#phrasing-content):

> Consists of *phrasing elements* intermixed with *normal character data*.

*Normal character data* is just that: unmarked up text. [*Phrasing elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) are:

> *a* or *em* or *strong* ... [a bunch of other elements none of which are *div*]

So, `<p><div></div></p>` is not valid HTML. Per the tag omission rules listed in the spec, the `<p>` tag is automatically closed by the `<div>` tag, which leaves the `</p>` tag without a matching `<p>`. The browser is well within its rights to attempt to correct it by adding an open `<p>` tag after the `<div>`:

```
<p></p><div></div><p></p>
```

You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<p>` and get consistent results from various browsers. Provide the browsers with valid HTML and they will behave better.

You can put `<div>` inside a `<div>` though so if you replace your `<p>` with `<div class="p">` and style it appropriately, you can get what you want.

Your reference at about.com disagrees with the specification at w3.org. Your reference is misleading you.

Comment: How about br tags?  Is it considered better practice to use DIV?

Comment: @Steve: Depends on the circumstances. I'd use a container to group elements and a `<br>` when I need a line-break within a group.

Comment: Note that HTML5 also *requires* the behavior of a `</p>` end tag resulting in an empty paragraph (although it likely only does so as a result of existing browser interop). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph

Comment: @BoltClock: Mark Amery added the "Per the tag omission rules listed in the spec, the `<p>` tag is automatically closed by the `<div>` tag, which leaves the `</p>` tag without a matching `<p>`" note, do we need more clarification? Maybe that whole paragraph could use a rewrite.

Comment: I think it looks OK. My comment was intended to clarify that not only is a browser well within its rights to correct the unmatched end tag, but it's required to do so. Perhaps it could be incorporated into the paragraph, but I don't think it needs a rewrite.

Answer (score 24):

It is not permitted to put block elements inside a p-tag.

However, in practice, this is not actually entirely true. The actual display value is in fact entirely irrelevant; the only thing that is considered is what the *default* display value is for the tag, e.g. "block" for divs and "inline" for spans. Changing the display value will still make the browser prematurely close the p-tag.

However, this also works the other way around. You can style a span-tag to behave exactly like a div-tag, but it will still be accepted inside the p environment.

So instead of doing this:

```
<p>
   <div>test</div>
</p>
```

You can do this:

```
<p>
   <span style="display:block">test</span>
</p>
```

Just remember that the browser validates the content of the p environment recursively, so even something like this:

```
<p>
   <span style="display:block">
       <div>test</div>
   </span>
</p>
```

Will result in the following:

```
<p>
   <span style="display:block"></span>
</p>
<div>test</div>
<p>
</p>
```

Comment: You say `<p><span>...</span></p>` is still technically invalid HTML but it isn't. `<span>` is a phrasing element which is alowed inside of `<p>` and changing its display value does not invalidate the HTML.

[Here's another article which discusses this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930438/putting-a-block-level-span-element-inside-a-p-element)

Comment: Setting a `span` to `display:block` and putting it inside a `p` may well be an unidiomatic way to use HTML/CSS (although Jukka makes an intriguing case at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18933182/1709587 for why it may sometimes be justified). It is, however, entirely valid HTML. When the HTML spec talks about elements' permitted content, it cares only about tag types - not their styling.

Answer (score 9):

The webdesign.about.com page is simply wrong; they probably misunderstood the HTML5 drafts. Allowing DIV inside P would cause great confusion; I don’t think it has even ever been considered during HTML5 development.

If you try to use DIV inside P, the DIV start tag will implicitly close the P element. This probably explains the things you’ve seen.

To avoid the problem, do not use P if the content contains, or may contain, a DIV element. Use DIV instead.

Comment: How about br tags?  Is it considered better practice to use DIV?

Comment: @Steve, yes, what about `br` tags? If you mean whether they may appear inside a `p` element, then yes, they can. The practical problem with `br` is that it does not turn a line to an *element*, making styling and scripting potentially problematic.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to place a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in the DOM because the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

`<P>` won't allow other element inside it. only `<span>` and `<strong>` element allowed.In `<p></p>` we can add only text related tags.
[refer this link to know more](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html)