# appendChild does not add a node to the end of the list of children

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

According to docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild, appendChild adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.

However, my example shows it adds the child to the top of the list of children.

How is that? Any idea why it happens against the docs?

According to docs, these code should add a new div element to the end of targetArea node, instead, it adds to the top of the node.

```
var targetArea = document.getElementById('nav');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var snippet = document.createTextNode('this is a new DIV');
div.appendChild(snippet);
targetArea.appendChild(div);
```

My code online:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennisboys/BRtYb/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems because you put `<div>` in `<p>` and the `<div>` will close the `<p>`.

Also see this question. [Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p)

Comment: Adding div inside p is wrong for sure, does it solve the problem though?

Comment: Thanks pktangyue! Never know there is a problem like this!

Comment: @MikeSpy I think using `<span>`  instead of `<div>` in `<p>` would be a better way.

Comment: Great to hear about it! I was trying exactly that on jsFiddle and for some reason it didn't work...

Comment: @MikeSpy what have you tried? see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRtYb/9/) it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly the same. As I said, for some strange reason didn't work that time. Anyways... I confirm it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the actual DOM structure you end up with.

In your jsFiddle, the node with id="nav" ends up with two children, a text node that says "I am P Content" and the div you appended.  The div is indeed being put as the last child node of the nav node just like it is supposed to.