# Dynamically generated links not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that uses jQuery to construct links and anchor tags based on existing HTML elements. It works in all browsers I tested except IE, where the output for the anchor tag was a little different.

Other browsers:

```
 <a class="courseshortcut" name="TitleJanuary12-13,2013"></a>
```

Internet Explorer:

```
 <a name="TitleJanuary12-13,2013" class="courseshortcut"/>
```

The generated links to these anchor tags look like this:

```
 <a href="#TitleJanuary12-13,2013">January 12-13, 2013 - Miami, FL</a>
```

The following section of code in the document.ready function adds the anchors:

```
 //adds the anchor tags
$('.courseentry').each(function() {
    var str = $(this).find('.coursetitle').html() + $(this).find('.coursedate').html();     
    $(this).prepend("<a class='courseshortcut' name='" + str.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "'></a>");
});
```

I can't figure out why this issue is occurring. Can someone enlighten me? A more complete version of the test script can be found [here](http://www.asmithspace.net/testing/appendtest.html).

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: @SLaks—other than the invalid HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.
The links don't work in IE. On my test page, they work fine with Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: You don't have a link because there's nothing between the opening and closing tags, and there's no `href` attribute. The problem isn't with IE.

Comment: @Drew02 Why are you links empty? Try putting some generic text in them, and see what happens.

Comment: @Sime Vidas They're anchor tags, which will be invisible on the page

Comment: @Drew02 @Blazemonger. These are anchors, no links. If you want a link to these anchors then `<a href="#TitleJanuary12-13,2013">January 12-13, 2013 - Miami, FL</a>`

Comment: In general, I find that if you need to have *70* `<br/>` tags in a row, you should possibly rethink your solution.

Comment: @aquinas . looks like OP just wanted to show the link effect. and he leave between the link and the anchor much space. And after 2. Anchor much space in order to show the effect for the 2.link.

Answer (score 0):

There are some invalid HTML in your page.Just open in IE and view in developer tool(F12). eg `<div> is inside <p>`
[find this link for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p)

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors in the IE developer view. I went ahead and cleaned up the page a bit, so there are no longer any errors when I use the w3.org validation page. The links to the anchor tags still won't function in IE.

Answer (score -1):

I think IE needs a file name or url before the hashtag

```
href="#TitleJanuary12-13,2013"
```

but i could stand corrected