# DIV are not showing inside p tags

Tags: html, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have a HTML like this:

```
<a class="nhr" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="" >
    <p class="top_dr_profle">
        <div class="my_doc_pic">
            <img src="images/profile_img.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="my_doc_cont">
            <p>Josh Dobstaff, MD</p>
            <p>Hospitalist</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </p>
    <p class="primary">Make Primary</p>
</a>
```

Here you can see 3 `<div/>`s inside `<p/>` tag with class `.top_dr_profle`. But when I see it in firebug in mozilla the `<div/>`s are appearing outside of the `<p/>` tags. I have attached the screen shot too of firebug.

[image]

Comment: this is invalid HTML! p tags are text containers not layout containers

Comment: your image is not visible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

`<p>` elements may not have `<div>` element child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

paragraph tag can not contain block level elements. div is a block level element

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span element inside parapragh elements so it would look like this:

```
<p class="top_dr_profle">
    <span class="my_doc_pic">
        <img src="images/profile_img.png" />
    </span>
</p>
```