# How can I wrap the element with div container if it not wrap up with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I tried to wrap the following element with div container, if it is not wrap up with.

```
<p class="fileDetails"><div class="filename">text goes here</div><div class="fileSize">text goes here</div></p>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put `<div>` elements inside of `<p>`s. (Down to the specs -- see also [Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p) ) if you're interested.

So you'll have to switch to a `<span>` that's styled the way you want, or probably semantically an unordered list makes more sense.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grahampcharles/ngcsr825/) showing how it could work.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ef43tgto/**

You should make .filename and .fileSize `<p>` tags and the .fileDetails a `<div>`. Then you can use jQuery .wrap()

```
<div class="fileDetails">
    <p class="filename">text goes here</p>
    <p class="fileSize">text goes here</p>
</div>

if ( !$('.container').length ) {
    $('.fileDetails').wrap('<div class="container" />')
}
```