# CSS general sibling combinator (ie ~)

Tags: css

I am trying to understand why the following example does not behave as expected.  I have a style that selects general siblings, but I also have children which I would not expect to be selected, but occasionally are.  Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem.
The first `div>div.h` is a descendant, and the `~` does NOT match it.  The second `p>div.h` is clearly a descendant, but the `~` selector DOES match it.    I tried in Chrome,Safari and Firefox, all behave the same.  I must be missing something.  Is `p` "special"?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .anchor ~ .h { color: orange }
      .anchor2 ~ .h { color: blue }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="h">black 1</div>
      <div class="h">black 2</div>
      <p class="anchor">the anchor</p>
      <div class="h">orange 1</div>
      <div>
        <div class="h">should be black</div>
      </div>
      <p>
        <div class="h">why isn't this black</div>
      </p>
      <div class="h">orange 2</div>
      <p class="anchor2">anchor2</p>
      <div class="h">blue 1</div>
      <div class="h">blue 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<div>` elements are not valid children of `<p>`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10763952/1612146)

Your browser corrects your errors (takes your `<div>` and places it after `<p>` instead of inside it) and by doing so, makes `div.h` a sibling of `.anchor`:

[image]

---

Now, if you use inline elements in your paragraphs, the browser doesn't correct your markup and you get your expected result:

```css
.anchor ~ .h {
    color: orange
}
.anchor2 ~ .h {
    color: blue
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="h">black 1</div>
    <div class="h">black 2</div>
    <p class="anchor">the anchor</p>
    <div class="h">orange 1</div>
    <div>
        <span class="h">should be black</span>
    </div>
    <p>
        <span class="h">why isn't this black</span>
    </p>
    <div class="h">orange 2</div>
    <p class="anchor2">anchor2</p>
    <div class="h">blue 1</div>
    <div class="h">blue 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I understand, the div wasn't actually a child of the p.  I found the following official description as well [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).  The `span` is a nice solution.