# Loading a video inside a toggler through Alloy UI (Liferay 6.2)

Tags: javascript, video, liferay, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I am trying to display a video player inside a modal window in Liferay 6.2 through Alloy UI, with no luck. I have a simple portlet with the following structure in `view.jsp`:

```
<div id="myToggler">
    <button class="header toggler-header-collapsed">Show Video</button>
    <p class="content toggler-content-collapsed">
        <div id="myVideo"></div>
    </p>
</div>
```

In the main JavaScript file, `main.js`, the toggler is loaded into the `#myToggler` layer, and the video is loaded into the `#myVideo` layer, which is, in fact, inside the toggler. The video is not loaded into the toggler, though.

```
YUI ( ).use (
    'aui-toggler',
    'aui-video',

    function (Y) {
        new Y.TogglerDelegate ({
            animated: true,
            closeAllOnExpand: true,
            container: '#myToggler',
            content: '.content',
            header: '.header',
            transition: {
                duration: .5,
                easing: 'cubic-bezier'
            }
        }).render ( );

        new Y.Video ({
            boundingBox: '#myVideo',
            ogvUrl: 'http://alloyui.com/video/movie.ogg',
            url: 'http://alloyui.com/video/movie.mp4'
        }).render ( );
    }
);
```

So, how can I load the video inside the toggler? Or, for that matter, how can I load any arbitrary Alloy UI widget inside another (e.g. a video player inside a  modal window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is due to the fact that, `TogglerDelegate` does not have a `render()` method. Also, [you should not put a `div` into a `p` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p#10763952). Instead, just make the toggler `content` into a `div`. See below for a runnable example:

```js
YUI ( ).use (
    'aui-toggler',
    'aui-video',

    function (Y) {
        new Y.TogglerDelegate ({
            animated: true,
            closeAllOnExpand: true,
            container: '#myToggler',
            content: '.content',
            header: '.header',
            transition: {
                duration: .5,
                easing: 'cubic-bezier'
            }
        });

        new Y.Video ({
            boundingBox: '#myVideo',
            ogvUrl: 'http://alloyui.com/video/movie.ogg',
            url: 'http://alloyui.com/video/movie.mp4'
        }).render ( );
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div id="myToggler">
    <button class="header toggler-header-collapsed">Show Video</button>
    <div class="content toggler-content-collapsed">
      <div id="myVideo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> [H]ow can I load any arbitrary Alloy UI widget inside another (e.g. a video player inside a modal window)?

One way to do this is to specify the outer widget's `boundingBox` and `contentBox`, and place the inner widget inside the `contentBox` of the outer widget. See below for a runnable example:

```js
YUI().use('aui-modal', 'aui-video', function(Y) {

  new Y.Modal({
    boundingBox: '#bb',
    contentBox: '#cb',
    headerContent: 'Modal header'
  }).render();

  new Y.Video({
    boundingBox: '#myVideo',
    ogvUrl: 'http://alloyui.com/video/movie.ogg',
    url: 'http://alloyui.com/video/movie.mp4'
  }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div class="yui3-skin-sam">
  <div id="bb">
    <div id="cb" style="background-color: grey;">
      <div id="myVideo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ups, sorry. Newbie mistake `:)`