# Why does React strangely render the <p> (paragraph) tag?

Tags: reactjs

React is doing strange things with the `<p>` tag. Using the same markup structure, with a `<p>` tag vs a `<div>` tag produces very different results. For example,

```
var withP = (
    <p>
      withP
      <div />
    </p>
);

var withDiv = (
    <div>
      withDiv
      <div />
    </div>
);
```

Here is what the generated markup looks like in chrome:

[image: screenshot from chrome dev tools]

#### [Here is a live jsbin demo.](http://jsbin.com/kufoje/1/edit?js,console,output)

#### Why does React render `<p>` differently than `<div>`?

Comment: Does React play nice with `<div />` even though it's not valid HTML?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p, this is not a React issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`<p>` can not have nested block elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). Chrome (not React) is transforming the markup to make it valid.