# JQuery Get Next first element class name

Tags: jquery

```
var cName = ($(".myclass").next().attr('class'));
alert(cName);

if (cName == "c1") {

$("#Output").addClass("green");
$("#Output").removeClass("red");

} else {

$("#Output").addClass("red");
$("#Output").removeClass("green");
}
```

---

```
<p class="myclass">If you click on me, I will disappear.
<span class="c1"></span>
<span class="c2"></span>
<span class="c3"></span>
<span class="c4"></span>
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
<div id="Output" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></div>
</p>
```

I am trying to get the `.classname` of the first `span` element. Why is jquery not fetching the next `span` element `.classname` ? Please help.

Comment: `span` is the child  of `<p>` so `.next()` wont work. Use `$(".myclass span:first")`

Comment: `$('myclass span:first-child').attr('class')`

Answer (score 1):

`next()` is getting the sibling of the `p` element, not the *first* child. To get the first child, do

```
var cName = $(".myclass").children().first().attr('class');
```

```js
console.log($(".myclass").children().first().attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="myclass">If you click on me, I will disappear.
  <span class="c1"></span>
  <span class="c2"></span>
  <span class="c3"></span>
  <span class="c4"></span>
  <div id="Output" style="width:25px; height:25px;"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Ammar, how to get class of first div child ? inside .myclass div there is different tags. i need to get 1st div element class name.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cName =($(".myclass").next().attr('class'));
```

Here `next()` element will get the next `<p>` sibling and not the `span` element..If you need to get next span element use this

```
var cName =$(".myclass span:first-child").attr('class');
```

Comment: var cName =$(".myclass span:first").attr('class'); not working. getting 'undefined' error. :(

Comment: it must be `first-child` not `first`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a proper way to define **div** tag inside **p** tag. And hence you are unable to access those child **div** elements.The opening **div** tag will automatically close the **p** tag. Because end tag of `<p>` elements are optional know.

It means `<p>` tags can contain only the inline elements.

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

Block elements are not allowed to define inside the `<p>` elements.

Please refer the following link, which describes about the block and inline elements  in detail:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

And also refer the following stack overflow links which has been already discussed:

[Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p)

[Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Hope this helps you....