# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I have a react app where I am using MUI. Its having two pages lets say Login & Signup. And both these pages were wrapped by a toplevel code:

```
function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
      <div
        role="tabpanelswitch"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
      >
        {value === index && (
          <Box>
            <Typography>{children}</Typography>
          </Box>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

return (
    <Grid
      container
      component="div"
      marginTop="10px"
      direction="row"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Paper style={paperStyle} elevation={10}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="disabled tabs example"
          TabIndicatorProps={{
            style: {
              backgroundColor: "#xxxxxxxx",
            },
          }}
          centered
        >
          <Tab label="Sign In" />
          <Tab label="Sign Up" />
        </Tabs>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
          <Login handleChange={handleChange} />
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
          <Signup />
        </TabPanel>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

**SignIn** | SignUp

After clicking the Login button, I am getting the above two pages for login/signup. But When clicking the login button, I am getting the following warning in the browser's console though no impact on the functionality:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 
        
    Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
    at p
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Typography (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46766:87)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Toolbar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45655:82)
    at header
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Paper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40510:82)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at AppBar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25701:83)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Grid (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33861:87)
    at Login (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3249:5)
    at p
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Typography (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46766:87)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Box (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50403:72)
    at div
    at TabPanel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:311:7)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Paper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40510:82)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6140:66
    at Grid (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33861:87)
    at SignInOutContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:348:74)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:108594:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:108527:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:107336:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73:56)
    at AuthContextProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5226:5)
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
validateDOMNesting @ react-dom.development.js:10849
createInstance @ react-dom.development.js:10930
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:22187
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26596
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26568
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

Similarly, total 5 warnings visible at different sections of the code.
I tried defining the **span** via components but still no improvement:

```
react-dom.development.js:86   
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.        
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <header> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.    
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <h2> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
```

- The login code is something like this:

```
  return (
    <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center">
      <AppBar color="inherit" position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <NavLink to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <Box
              component="img"
              src={devicon}
              width="30px"
              height="30px"
              paddingRight={1}
              paddingTop={0.8}
            />
          </NavLink>
          <Typography
            color="green"
            flexGrow={1}
            fontWeight="bold"
            display="flex"
            sx={{
              alignSelf: "center",
              fontSize: { xs: "1.125rem", sm: "2.125rem" },
            }}
          >
            devplatform
          </Typography>
          <Stack spacing={1} direction="row">
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              color="success"
              size="small"
              href="/login"
            >
              Login
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="success"
              size="small"
              href="/signup"
            >
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Stack>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Grid
        container
        component="span"
        direction="row"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        <Paper style={paperStyle}>
          <Grid align="center">
            <Avatar style={avatarStyle}>
              <LockOutlinedIcon />
            </Avatar>
            <h2 style={headerStyle}>Member Login</h2>
          </Grid>
          <Formik initialValues={initialValues}>
            {(props) => (
              <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                <span className="uname">
                  <Field
                    as={TextField}
                    label="Username"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Enter Username"
                    variant="standard"
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    color="success"
                    helperText={<ErrorMessage name="email" />}
                    type="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </span>
                <span className="passwd">
                  <Field
                    as={TextField}
                    label="Password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Enter Password"
                    variant="standard"
                    type="password"
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    color="success"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    helperText={<ErrorMessage name="password" />}
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </span>
                <span className="login-remember">
                  <Field
                    as={FormControlLabel}
                    name="remember"
                    control={<Checkbox color="success" />}
                    label="Remember me"
                  />
                </span>
                <span className="signin-button">
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    type="submit"
                    color="success"
                    style={btnStyle}
                    fullWidth
                    disabled={props.isSubmitting}
                  >
                    {props.isSubmitting ? "Loading" : "Sign In"}
                  </Button>
                  {error && (
                    <span className="span">Wrong email or password</span>
                  )}
                </span>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
          <span className="endcontent">
            <Typography
              component={'div'}
              sx={{ fontFamily: "Roboto, sans-serif", marginTop: "25px" }}
            >
              <Link href="/forget-password"> Forgotten password?</Link>
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              component={'div'}
              sx={{ fontFamily: "Roboto, sans-serif" }}
            >
              {" "}
              New to this domain ?{" "}
              <Link onClick={() => handleChange("event", 1)}>Join now </Link>
            </Typography>
          </span>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Your options are (1) correct the markup or (2) disable the warnings and continue with incorrect markup.  Which are you looking to do?  What have you tried in that attempt?

Comment: I want to go with (1) to fix the markup. But how to do that ? I checked in many places and found that its an issue with React itself and has to be fixed by the maintainer itself. As mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928567/div-cannot-appear-as-a-descendant-of-p, I have already tried that but still the same.

Comment: By editing the markup so that `<p>` is not a descendant of `<p>` (similarly with the rest of the warnings).  Somewhere in your component structure you are incorrectly using either a `<p>` or a component which renders to a `<p>` as a placeholder for more complex content.  Which is invalid.  A `<p>` is a *paragraph*.  It's meant to hold a paragraph of text.  Edit your markup to reflect that.

Comment: First, check how the component is rendering by inspecting the element. Can you provide an example of your components to see how they are nested?

Comment: @Udayendu: *"and found that its an issue with React itself and has to be fixed by the maintainer"* - I don't see how that's the case, but if your assertion is that your code is correct and React must be broken then it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: @David, may be I am rendering it wrongly. I have updated some test codes for the reference. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Udayendu: Given the code shown, that's an interesting question.  Note that in the code shown, `<Login>` is an immediate child of `<TabPanel>`.  But in the error, the structure from parent to child for these is: `TabPanel -> div -> Box -> div -> Typography -> p -> Login`  The problem is that `<p>` in that hierarchy.  But I don't see from the code shown how that's being inserted into that structure.  Unless there's some customization happening in the `<TabPanel>` that isn't shown here?  This could involve some more debugging on your part.

Comment: @David, you are correct. TabPanel is a function thats being used to handle the tab switch between Login/SignUp. I have added that to the code. You can take a look now.

Comment: Thanks @Akis for pointing to the rendering. The wrapper was going wrong but its working now :)

Comment: @Udayendu: Ah, that makes sense now.  I thought `<TabPanel>` would have been something built-in to MUI or something of that nature.  Indeed, that `<Typography>` would be the culprit.  I would even suggest replacing the `<Typography>` entirely, rather than changing its rendered component.  Keeping the semantics of the structure/hierarchy sensible will go a long way for debugging and maintenance over time.  Typography elements should really just be text (with minimal complexity), not high-level containers for all sorts of potential elements.

Comment: @David, yes will re-design this things soon once the initial prototyping will be done. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @Udayendu in your code you are using `<span className="...">` which seems like a bad practice if you have other lements that render into a `<div>`, button or `<Field>`. I would strongly suggest to also change them to `<div>`

Comment: @Akis, Thanks for the recommendation. I was actually using <div> only but specifically for this issue I changed those to <span>. But I will move them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@David, thanks for explaining the flow.
I was applying the change in the wrong place.

After adding **component={"div"}** in the TabPanel function, it started working as well.

The working code is:

```
function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
      <div
        role="tabpanelswitch"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
      >
        {value === index && (
          <Box>
            <Typography component={"div"}>{children}</Typography>
          </Box>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```