# TextField error in console in FluentUI React

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

I am using TextField component provided by Fluent UI in React wherein I am rendering a custom validation error message (JSX.Element).

```
 <TextField
    value={"ABC"}
    onChange={(_, newValue: string | undefined) =>                   
             onValueChange(newValue)}
    errorMessage={item.validationError|| undefined}
 />;
```

The validation error (referred to as `item.validationError` in above code) is a JSX element which makes use of the Stack component provided by Fluent UI. Pseudo code -

```
<Stack horizontal horizontalAlign="start">
   <Stack.Item> {} </Stack.Item>
   <Stack.Item> {} </Stack.Item>
</Stack>
```

For some reason, whenever validation error comes up, this error comes up in console - **[image: strong text]**

It's not impacting the functionality in any way, but how can this error be removed and why is it coming ? I am suspecting this is because Stack is being used inside the TextField component and Stack internally uses `div` whereas TextField uses `p` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is printed by your browser that checks for certain kind of HTML nesting rules. E.g. block elements should not appear as children of inline elements.

p should only contain inline elements.
But a div is a block element.

Your Stack component uses a div element. That is why you see the warning.

Inline and block elements have different attributes. One of the most significant is that block elements take always 100% width.

I don't know the UI library you are using but maybe you can use a different tag for the Stack.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928635

Comment: Can you edit your answer ? Some parts of your answer seem to be missing. Do you mean p is an inline element and div is a block element ?

Comment: Thanks. Updated my post. Didn't see that the content was escaped as HTML content.