# console.js:213 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>. at div

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
at p
at http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-WQ5FBX7J.js?v=539aff10:2964:50
at Typography2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-KIELVNL2.js?v=539aff10:134:22)
at div
at YourReq
at p
at http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-WQ5FBX7J.js?v=539aff10:2964:50
at Typography2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-KIELVNL2.js?v=539aff10:134:22)
at div
at http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-WQ5FBX7J.js?v=539aff10:2964:50
at Box3 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-WQ5FBX7J.js?v=539aff10:5574:19)
at div...
```

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yimvg.png)

I ran into this error in MUI and I also don't want to add a
`component={'span'}` **for every line of code**
I don't know where the problems of this error came from, but it started all of a sudden and now it doesn't end anymore

```
import * as React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
export default function YourReq() {
  return (
<div>
  <Typography >
    هر چیزی لازم داری با زدن دکمه درخواست جدید اعلام کن هر چقدر کارهای
    بیشتری از درخواست های دیگران انجام بدی دیگران هم درخواست های بیشتری برای
    شما انجام خواهند داد
  </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I removed Typography components and used the `document.querySelectorAll("p > div")`
to find the exact problem but it seems I have to do it for every component and it's not a functional solution

Comment: It is impossible to help without posting some sort of code. Stack overflow should not be used for this purpose. Please add code so that you're able to aid others in helping you find a solution. Can you at least paste the entire error?

Comment: here you are the picture and code

Comment: Your title does not match your error. `<p>` is NOT `<div>`  but: "Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing </p> tag. See "Tag omission" below." ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p  SO a `<p>` cannot contain a `<p>` per that

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a common problem with Material UI and `<Typography>`. The cause, as the error message suggests, is improper nesting of block-level markup ie. a browser would terminate an open paragraph when encountering another `<p>` start-element tag. This behavior of browsers is rooted in HTML's basic construction of inline content wrapped into block-level content and was well-known and immediately apparent when SGML was used to describe HTML, but isn't anymore now with HTML 5 and later described in a stand-alone specification that moreover frequently isn't updating references to element categories and enumerations of allowed or disallowed elements as new elements are added or content models are changed. See eg. https://sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html for a more general discussion of tag inference in HTML and SGML.

The solution is to configure `<Typography>` to use a different container element such as `span` according to [<div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928567/div-cannot-appear-as-a-descendant-of-p?rq=2).