# jQuery tooltip that includes a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using jQuery to show as a tooltip whatever is in the "title" of the element. In general it works great. But if I want to display a table as a tooltip by having the entire `<table>...</table>` inside the title, it doesn't work. I've seen this in action, so I know it is possible!

I saw another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383591/show-table-in-a-tooltip-with-jquery) here, but it seems to be for an older version of jQuery tooltip (?). I don't want to define the tooltiptext in JavaScript, I want it to show whatever is in the title. Like it is explained [here](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: You need to investigate the popover component - thats the dialog element that has the ability to put html into the body of the dialog and a header etc.

Comment: How are you trying to add the table's markup to the tooltip title? Please update your question to show this.

Comment: Just setting the title to a string that contains the table: `<span title="<table><thead><tr><th>Call Status</th><th>Date</th><th>Calling</th></tr></thead><tbody>...`