# An empty <p> tag is automatically getting inserted, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

An empty `<p></p>` tag is getting inserted automatically when the page is rendered, I'm not sure, how to get rid of it. Which is adding unwanted space on the webpage.

[image: Screenshot the Chrome Developer Tools with the <p> tag in question being highlighted]

I'm not sure how I can get rid of it. I'm trying to set the margin-bottom for the `<p>` to 0px, even that isn't getting applied as well.

I would be really thankful to anyone who could help me with fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code which renders the HTML block:
The `<p></p>` tag gets generated dynamically, but not sure, how it is getting generated from the code.

```
{% if job_detail.type != '' and job_detail.type is not None or job_detail.age_limit != '' and job_detail.age_limit is not None %}
     <hr />
     <div class="row">
     {% if job_detail.type != '' and job_detail.type is not None %}
       <div class="col-md-6">
         <h3 class="card-title topic-title">JOB TYPE</h3>
         <p class="card-text topic-text last-child">{{ job_detail.type|linebreaks }}</p>
       </div>
     {% endif %}
     {% if job_detail.age_limit != '' and job_detail.age_limit is not None %}
       <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 mt-sm-4 mt-md-0">
         <h3 class="card-title topic-title">AGE LIMIT</h3>
         <p class="card-text topic-text last-child">{{ job_detail.age_limit|linebreaks }}</p>
       </div>
     {% endif %}
     </div>
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don't show where the html is being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the following style to the paragraph tag ```margin-bottom: 0!important

Thanks everyone for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

@Shahzan, welcome here, normaly it is the best way to remove the p-tag because you don't need that.
If you have included bootstrap in your webpage you can use an css-classes like "pb-2" to fix the padding on the bottom.

I think your tool generates an p-tag.
Maybe you can tell use more about your setup.

Also you should use some better IDE, maybe some PHPStorm, Atom or Sublime.

```html
<div class="pb-2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @larabee. I'm using Atom.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which was caused by a `div` being inside the `p` tag, which is not allowed. The browser tried to correct it and added the empty `<p></p>`

See: [Putting <div> inside <p> is adding an extra <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p)

Answer (score -1):

You can assign "display:none;" to this empty auto generated blank p tag. I would like to recommend to add a class parent element (.col-md-6) of child ".card-title" and then use p:last-child pseudo element to make it "display:none". It will solve your problem. I have written a snippet for you so that you will get better idea of this approach, but when you will try to implement it please add class as per mentioned on above lines. For the reference purpose add below snippet in the head section of your project :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .card.mt-2 .card-body.pt-3.pb-3 > .row > .col-md-6 p:last-child {
        display:none;
      }
 </style>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response. I did try adding your snippet to the head section and also added the last-child as a class to the p tag, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Shahzan: Can you please some more snippet for this. I will understand actual hierarchy of the code and provide you best solution. Also, I am assuming that this empty <p></p> tag is generating dynamically. If it is static or I can say in your control, removing this tag is the best option.

Comment: Thanks again, I have added at the end of the question itself. I hope this makes things much clear now.