# paragraph renders block child elements after itself

Tags: html

The `<p></p>` element renders block child elements after itself.

I tested other block elements but they are rendered as in the source code (except the 'p' element), I'm sure this is something obvious but what?

Source Code

`<p> myParagraph <div> child's div </div> </p>`

This is how it's rendered

`<p> myParagraph </p> <div> child's div </div>`

Comment: It is not valid HTML to put a `<div>` inside a `<p>`.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p