# Why isn't Velocity displaying <div>'s that should be displayed as "display: flex;" correctly?

Tags: java, html, templates, velocity

I have problem with Apache Velocity engine.

I have a piece of html in my template:

```
<p>
    <span><b>${contextString}: ${context.contextTitle}</b></span>
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div>${published}</div>
        <div>${context.published}</div>
        <div>${noWorkflow}</div>
        <div>${context.reviewed}</div>
    </div>
</p>
```

But when I test this template, Velocity seems to somehow convert those DIVs into regular `display: block;` or is ignoring `display: flex;` completely, displaying all items in new lines.

Why is Velocity displaying this incorrectly? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Velocity problem: outside of `$references` and `#directives`, Velocity does not interpret the text it is formatting, would it be HTML or else.

There is at least one HTML problem in your code that may cause this: `<p>` tags cannot contain `<div>` tags, so the `<p>` is closed when it encounters the first `<div>`. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10763952/710286).