# Vue: How to do a nested loop and traverse a multidimensional array?

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array, vuejs2

I have a multidimensional array called `verses`:

```
export default {
  name: "Example",
  data: () => ({
    verses: [['First', 'Verse'], ['Second', 'Verse']]
  })
}
```

I am trying to traverse the multidimensional `verses` array as such:

```
<p v-for="(verse, verse_index) in verses" :key="verse_index">
    <div v-for="(word, word_index) in verse" :key="word_index">
        {{ word }}
    </div>
</p>
```

I am getting this error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "verse" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

How do I traverse a multidimensional array in Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<p>` element cannot contain a `<div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p), so the browser hoists it outside, resulting in this template:

```html
<p v-for="(verse, verse_index) in verses" :key="verse_index">
</p>
<div v-for="(word, word_index) in verse" :key="word_index">
  {{ word }}
</div>
<p></p>
```

Notice how the second `v-for` is outside the first `v-for` that defined `verse`.

If you really intended to insert the `<div>` inside `<p>` for some reason, you can workaround the issue by wrapping the `<div>` in a `<template>` to prevent the browser from parsing it:

```html
<p v-for="(verse, verse_index) in verses" :key="verse_index">
  <template> 
    <div v-for="(word, word_index) in verse" :key="word_index">
        {{ word }}
    </div>
  </template>
</p>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEeJGog)

Comment: Is there a way to traverse over the words in the verse without any tag (div or otherwise)? I just want all the words to go into the p tag. How can that be achieved without the use of any tag?

Comment: @etayluz Just do `{{ verse.join(' ') }}` ([demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yLMoYNL)).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are passing the data value correctly, but I have changed that a bit and its working fine for me .

```
   data:  () => {
    return {
      verses: [['First', 'Verse'], ['Second', 'Verse']]
    }
   }
```

And one suggestion. Its not recommended to use `div` tag inside a `p` tag

Comment: The OP's code is shorthand for what you're proposing.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using vue syntax in the above code.

The problem is because `<div>` is inside `<p>`

So this will work

```
<div v-for="(verse, verse_index) in verses" :key="verse_index">
  <div v-for="(word, word_index) in verse" :key="word_index">
    {{ word }}
  </div>
</div>
```