# How to disable drag of `<a>` element when dragging a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have an HTML table, wrapped in a div, wrapped in an anchor element so that the entire table links to an external URL. The div has a fixed with, and has `overflow-x: auto` so that it scrolls horizontally.

When I click and drag the horizontal scrollbar, it starts to move the content horizontally, but then it starts dragging the entire anchor element.

Is there any way to disable this with just HTML or CSS? This is being rendered in an email so I can't use JS.

For example, HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" >
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>
        <th>Header5</th>
        <th>Header6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
        <td>Data5</td>
        <td>Data6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</a>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: You could wrap the contents of the `<a>` and all the children in a `<p>` element .. I think that should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can make the parent of all of the HTML elements you've added here a `<p>` element, and that should stop the clicking of the scroll bar from acting as if the entire thing is a link:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="http://example.com" >
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Header1</th>
          <th>Header2</th>
          <th>Header3</th>
          <th>Header4</th>
          <th>Header5</th>
          <th>Header6</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td>
          <td>Data2</td>
          <td>Data3</td>
          <td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td>
          <td>Data6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I think this is exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: Actually, this doesn’t seem to work in practice. The div automatically closes the p tag and the table isn’t linked anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow @noahmoss. What do you mean "div automatically closes the p tag" ?

Comment: This is the issue I'm seeing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763780/putting-div-inside-p-is-adding-an-extra-p

Seems like a div just can't within a <p> element, so the browser will close the <p> before the div and add another one after it. The linked JSFidddle has an example.

Comment: Actually, it worked after I swapped the order of the `<a>` and `<div>` elements, and then nested them both in the `<p>`. Don't understand why, but thanks for your help!